# dynamic conditions in where clause of Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a class:

```
public class Snowman
{

    public Snowman(string Appearance, string Colour, string Name)
    {
        this.AppearanceProp = Appearance;
        this.ColourProp = Colour;
        this.NameProp = Name;
    }
    public string AppearanceProp { get; set; }
    public string ColourProp { get; set; }

    public string NameProp
    { get; set; }
}
```

a list of snowmen objects:

```
List<Snowman> snowmen = new List<Snowman>()
{
    new Snowman("Proud", "White", "Jose"),
    new Snowman("Dreamer", "Silver", "Mark"),
    new Snowman("Dreamer", "Silver", "James"),
    new Snowman("Jaded", "White", "Jerry"),
    new Snowman("Joyous", "White", "Mark"),
    new Snowman("Joyous", "White", "Jose"),
    new Snowman("Joyous", "White", "James")
};
```

and a list of columns I want to filter the list of snowmen (the list updates dynamically at runtime):

```
var Column1 = "Appearance";
var Column2 = "Colour";
string Column3 = null;
```

so I should be able to dynamically filter using a dynamic linq with a dynamic where clause, something like this:

```
var chosenOnes = snowmen
    .Where(a =>
           Column1 != null ? a.GetType().GetProperty(Column1 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i]  &&
           Column2 != null ? a.GetType().GetProperty(Column1 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i+1] 
                );
```

This gives a syntax error,

> expecting :

Not sure what I am missing

values is :

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "joyous", "white" };
```

Comment: The syntax for the ternary operator is `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`. You forgot to put the `: ifFalse` part in your `Where` call.

Comment: True. Thank you zdimension. Thing is I don't want anything to happen, not even null. I want the whole condition to be ignored, as if it didn't exist, if the Column1 is null, not sure how to phrase the syntax for that.

Comment: You wouldn't use a ternary operator then, just use a regular old-fashioned if clause.

Comment: @Sami you can then replace the whole ternary operator by a `&&` operator: `Column1 != null && a.GetType().[...].ToString() == values[i]`. This is called short-circuiting, it means that if Column1 is indeed null, then the second operand will not be evaluated at all.

Comment: I guess the question is how to write a Func<Snowman, bool> predicate which is what the where clause seems to process. i am not familiar with Func<T,bool> though

Comment: Try using the code I wrote in my comment, if I understood what you're trying to do then it should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chosenOnes = snowmen
    .Where(a =>
        (Column1 == null || a.GetType().GetProperty(Column1 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i])
        && (Column2 == null || a.GetType().GetProperty(Column2 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i+1])
        && (Column3 == null || GetType().GetProperty(Column3 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i+2])
    );
```

...or use collections to DRY this up:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
    { "Appearance", "Joyous" },
    { "Colour",     "White" }
};

var chosenOnes = snowmen;
foreach(var filter in filters)
{
    chosenOnes = chosenOnes.Where(a => 
        a.GetType()
         .GetProperty(filter.Key + "Prop")
         .GetValue(a, null) == filter.Value
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can do this:

```
var chosenOnes = snowmen;

if (Column1 != null)
    chosenOnes = chosenOnes.Where(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(Column1 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i]);

if (Column2 != null)
    chosenOnes = chosenOnes.Where(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(Column2 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i+1]);

if (Column3 != null)
    chosenOnes = chosenOnes.Where(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(Column3 + "Prop").GetValue(a, null).ToString() == values[i+2]);
```

Just apply the `Where` clauses for each column if they aren't `null`.